# ODE $f:\text{<0 if $tx > 0$},\text{>0 if $tx<0$}$; show that $x(t)\equiv0$ is the only solution to $\dot{x}=f(t,x)\hspace{0,3cm}, x(0)=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ continuous fulfilling $$  \begin{cases}
>     f(t,x)<0, & \text{if $xt>0$}.\\
>     f(t,x)>0, & \text{if $xt<0$}.
>   \end{cases}
> $$
>   Show that, $x(t)\equiv0$ is the only solution to the initial value problem 
>   $$\dot{x}=f(t,x)\hspace{1cm}  x(0)=0$$

So obviously $x(t)\equiv0$ solves the problem on $\mathbb{R}^2$ in order to show that it's the only solution I would try to use the Picard-Lindelöf theorem. In order to be able to use it I would furthermore have to prove that $f$ is locally Lipschitz in $x$. But how can I do this ? I know of this theorem that says that if $f$ is locally differentiable w.r.t $x$ it's locally Lipschitz. Would that help ?

Comment: Does x=0 even solve it?

Comment: Well I assume that any function that respects these two constraints is a viable option

Comment: @ChristianSinger from which book is this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The continuity of $f$ implies that $f(t, 0) = 0$ for all $t \in \Bbb R$, so that $x(t) \equiv 0$ is a solution.

For any solution $x$ which is defined in an interval $I$ containing $t=0$
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(x^2(t)) = 2 x(t) \dot x(t) = 2 x(t)f(t, x(t)) \begin{cases}
\le 0 & \text{  if } t > 0 \\
\ge 0 & \text{  if } t < 0
\end{cases}
$$
because if $x(t) \ne 0$ then $x(t)$ and $f(t, x(t))$ have the opposite sign for $t> 0$, and the same sign for $t < 0$.

It follows that $x^2(t) \le x^2(0) = 0$.

Comment: How does it come, that we now have $t$ instead of $xt$ in the if conditions to the right ?

Comment: @ChristianSinger: You have to consider all possible combinations. For example, if $t > 0$ and $x(t) < 0$ then $f(t, x(t)) > 0$ so that the product $x(t) \cdot f(t, x(t))$ is negative, and so on. And if $t=0$ or $x(t)=0$ then the product is zero.

Comment: Ah! I see! You could take the coordinate systems with axes $x$ and $t$ and get that in quadrant II and IV $f$ is always positive and in I and III always negative. (except for the axes themselves)

Comment: @ChristianSinger: Exactly. Or put it like this: The product is zero if $t=0$ or $x(t) = 0$. Otherwise $x(t)$ and $f(t,x(t))$ have the opposite/same sign if $t$ is positive/negative.

Comment: This might be coming a bit late but upon reading this answer again, I wonder how the continuity of $f$ implies that $x(t)\equiv 0$ is a solution.

Comment: @ChristianSinger: Continuity of $f$ implies that $f(t, 0) = 0$.

Comment: I think I figured it out, since these conditions in combination with continuity say that $f$ has to be zero on the axes spanned by $t$ and $x$ (If we imagine it geometricaly for a second) we get that since with $x(t)\equiv 0$ we are in fact on such an axis and hence $f$ has to be zero.